# javafx 2.1 how to save an Image after modification using ColorAdjust

Tags: image, javafx

I just make a class that let me modify an image like saturation brightness, contrast and hue using ColorAjust Class.

But i dont know how to save that image after making those modifications.

Here is the code:

```
final Stage imageProcessStage = new Stage();
        imageProcessStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        imageImageProcess = new Image(ImagePathImageProcess);
        imageViewImageProcess = ImageViewBuilder.create().image(imageImageProcess).build();
        ColorAdjust colorAdjust = ColorAdjustBuilder.create().build();
        imageViewImageProcess.setEffect(colorAdjust);
        // 
        Label saturationLabel = LabelBuilder.create().text("Saturation").build();
        GridPane.setConstraints(saturationLabel, 0, 0);
        Slider saturationSlider = SliderBuilder.create().value(50).build();
        colorAdjust.saturationProperty().bind(saturationSlider.valueProperty().divide(50).subtract(1));
        GridPane.setConstraints(saturationSlider, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setHgrow(saturationSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Label saturationValueLabel = LabelBuilder.create().minWidth(75).maxWidth(75).build();
        saturationValueLabel.textProperty().bind(colorAdjust.saturationProperty().multiply(100).asString("%.2f%%"));
        GridPane.setConstraints(saturationValueLabel, 2, 0);
        // 
        Label hueLabel = LabelBuilder.create().text("Hue").build();
        GridPane.setConstraints(hueLabel, 0, 1);
        Slider hueSlider = SliderBuilder.create().value(50).build();
        colorAdjust.hueProperty().bind(hueSlider.valueProperty().divide(50).subtract(1));
        GridPane.setConstraints(hueSlider, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setHgrow(hueSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Label hueValueLabel = LabelBuilder.create().minWidth(75).maxWidth(75).build();
        hueValueLabel.textProperty().bind(colorAdjust.hueProperty().multiply(100).asString("%.2f%%"));
        GridPane.setConstraints(hueValueLabel, 2, 1);
        // 
        Label brightnessLabel = LabelBuilder.create().text("Brightness").build();
        GridPane.setConstraints(brightnessLabel, 0, 2);
        Slider brightnessSlider = SliderBuilder.create().value(50).build();
        colorAdjust.brightnessProperty().bind(brightnessSlider.valueProperty().divide(50).subtract(1));
        GridPane.setConstraints(brightnessSlider, 1, 2);
        GridPane.setHgrow(brightnessSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Label brightnessValueLabel = LabelBuilder.create().minWidth(75).maxWidth(75).build();
        brightnessValueLabel.textProperty().bind(colorAdjust.brightnessProperty().multiply(100).asString("%.2f%%"));
        GridPane.setConstraints(brightnessValueLabel, 2, 2);
        // 
        Label contrastLabel = LabelBuilder.create().text("Contrast").build();
        GridPane.setConstraints(contrastLabel, 0, 3);
        Slider contrastSlider = SliderBuilder.create().value(50).build();
        colorAdjust.contrastProperty().bind(contrastSlider.valueProperty().divide(50).subtract(1));
        GridPane.setConstraints(contrastSlider, 1, 3);
        GridPane.setHgrow(contrastSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Label contrastValueLabel = LabelBuilder.create().minWidth(75).maxWidth(75).build();
        contrastValueLabel.textProperty().bind(colorAdjust.contrastProperty().multiply(100).asString("%.2f%%"));
        GridPane.setConstraints(contrastValueLabel, 2, 3);

        //Validate Button
        Button btnValider = new Button("Valider");
        btnValider.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {   

              // SAVE IMAGE HERE

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to [JavaFX 2.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) and use the following code in your button event handler.

```
ImageIO.write(
  SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(
   imageViewImageProcess.snapshot(null, null), null
  ),
  "png",
  new File("valider.png")
);
```

Note that the 2.2 is currently in developer preview rather than a GA product, so you may encounter some issues and bugs until the new 2.2 methods have been thoroughly QAed.

Here is a complete, executable example: https://gist.github.com/2870355

Comment: thks for your effort but is there another way to do that in JavaFX 2.1 because I encountered a lot of issues in the 2.2 release like the TreeView that has a lot of bugs.
Thks

Comment: See http://www.aljoscha-rittner.de/blog/archive/2011/03/09/javafxdev-screen-capture-tool-with-200-lines-and-500ms-startup-time/

Answer (score 2):

A general purpose and simpler version of the code:

```
private void saveImage(
    Image i, 
    String extension, 
    String pathname) 
throws IOException {

ImageIO.write(
    SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(
        image, 
        null), 
    extension, 
    new File(
        pathname));
}
```